# Operation on a specified array's column using same column index - previous row in the array

Tags: python, numpy

The intention is do it without a for-loop or while-loop and, if it is possible, with a faster loop:

```
def multiply(x):
    return x * 10


a = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(5, 5))

print(f"array a = {a}")

a_multiplied = list(map(multiply, a))

print(f"multiply of a = {a_multiplied}")
```

It begins like this:

```
array a = [
 [4 6 1 5 9]
 [7 9 4 5 9]
 [8 9 6 5 6]
 [8 6 4 4 3]
 [2 4 2 9 4]
]
```

And returns this:

```
multiplied of a = [array([40, 60, 10, 50, 90]), array([70, 90, 40, 50, 90]), array([80, 90, 60, 50, 60]), array([80, 60, 40, 40, 30]), array([20, 40, 20, 90, 40])]
```

How can I use the previous row and same column to substitute the 10 in my `multiply` function?

Example:

```
from this:

array a = [
 [4 6 1 5 9]
 [7 9 4 5 9]
 [8 9 6 5 6]
 [8 6 4 4 3]
 [2 4 2 9 4] 
]

the process:

array a = [
 [4 6 |1| 5 9]
 [7 9 |4| 5 9] Multiply 4 * 1(previus row and same index)
 [8 9 |6| 5 6] Multiply 6 * 4(previus row and same index)
 [8 6 |4| 4 3] Multiply 4 * 6(previus row and same index)
 [2 4 |2| 9 4] Multiply 2 * 4(previus row and same index)
]

to this:

array a = [
 [4 6 |1 | 5 9]
 [7 9 |4 | 5 9] 
 [8 9 |24| 5 6] 
 [8 6 |24| 4 3] 
 [2 4 |8 | 9 4] 
]
```

Comment: 1) These values are not squares, they are multiplied by 10. 2) Have a look into / do some (more) research on **slice notation**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As S3DEV pointed out, you can [take](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#slice) [slices](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html) of your numpy arrays.
So for example, let's take your array

```
a = np.array([[4, 6, 1, 5, 9],
              [7, 9, 4, 5, 9],
              [8, 9, 6, 5, 6],
              [8, 6, 4, 4, 3],
              [2, 4, 2, 9, 4]])
```

We can take all but the last row with `a[:-1,:]` and all but the first row with `a[1:,:]` so you can do your multiplication with `b = a[:-1,:] * a[1:,:]`, giving

```
[[28 54  4 25 81]
 [56 81 24 25 54]
 [64 54 24 20 18]
 [16 24  8 36 12]]
```

If you wanted only one column, then like the one you are showing in your example, you could slice further: `b = a[:-1,2] * a[1:,2]` gives `[ 4 24 24  8]`, or as described in your example `[1 * 4, 4 * 6, 6 * 4, 4 * 2]`.

**EDIT**: *(and hat-tip to Ali_Sh for noticing)* To insert something like this directly into your existing `numpy.array` as you show in your question, you could just do something like `a[1:,2] *= a[:-1,2]` giving `a` as:

```
[[ 4  6  1  5  9]
 [ 7  9  4  5  9]
 [ 8  9 24  5  6]
 [ 8  6 24  4  3]
 [ 2  4  8  9  4]]
```